# C# : How can I resolve my textboxe error in a Setup Project?

Tags: c#, textbox, setup-project

I create a setup project for my windows service.
I add a `textboxes(A)` in my user interface, I add the first edit property which is `EDIT1`.

[image: textboxe]

[image: property edit1]

When I go to my custom actions -> install -> primary output and in `CustomActionData` I add `/dbname = [EDIT1]`

[image: custom action data]

I build my windows service and my setup project but when I want to install my project I have this error :

[image: install error]

And when I click on ok I have this error too :

[image: install state]

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces in the CustomActionData property? So it reads /dbname=[EDIT1]

Comment: @RyanThomas ... It was that ... I'm bad. Thank you for your help ^^' Just a question before how can I add value of Edit1 in my project ?

Comment: On the properties  for the textbox page there is one called "Edit1Value" you can set this.

Comment: @RyanThomas not the init value of edit1Value but the value of Edit1 write by the user.

Comment: Do you mean access the value in your custom action? You should be able to do something like session.CustomActionData or session.Property("CustomActionData") and then get it from there. I can't remember exactly as have moved over to WiX.

Comment: @RyanThomas Thank you I will try it.

Comment: @RyanThomas Are there any solution without Wix ?

Comment: Yes, that should pass the value correctly so not sure why it is not working. What are you trying to do with the value? Is it just not passing to the custom action? I notice you pass it to the primary output and not a custom action, so I'm confused what you are trying to do. What's the installer class look like?

Comment: Sorry, I believe to access the property in your Installer class you need to use Context.Parameters["dbname"].ToString()

Comment: @RyanThomas ty I see it but I can access to this only in  ProjectInstaller I try to access to this in other class

Comment: Yes that's expected behaviour. If this other class is part of the application and not the installer then you should write it to the app.config / registry or somewhere and then access it from their in your application. If this other class is part of your custom action then you could pass it in via a constructor.

Comment: @RyanThomas I try to write it in app.config but during the installation the app.config is not in the path of the project that's my issue actually.

Comment: @RyanThomas I create a ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949715/how-can-i-get-custom-action-data-of-a-setup-project-in-c

Comment: Good idea, I have responded over there. I will put my original comment as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces.

/dbname=[EDIT1]

A space is used to pass multiple parameters.

/dbname=[EDIT1] /dbserver=[EDIT2]