# How can I get custom action data of a setup project in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-services, setup-project, custom-action

I create a windows service and a setup project for my service.
In my windows service I can get my customer action data thinks to this :

```
Context.Parameters["dbname"]
```

But I want to access to the value of my customer action data in my service to use it in my project.

Someone have any idea how to do it in c# ?

**UPDATE**

In my ProjectInstaller :

```
public ProjectInstaller()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);
    string dbName = Context.Parameters["dbname"];
    AppHelper.Save(dbName+" "+ Context.Parameters["targetdir"].ToString());

    string xml = Context.Parameters["targetdir"].ToString() + "App.config";

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(xml);

    XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);

    foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select(@"/configuration.appSettings/add[@key='dbName']"))
    {
        nav.SetValue(dbName);
    }

    document.Save(xml);
}
```

the **app.config** of my windows service :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="dbName" value="totodb"/>
  </appSettings>

  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I try to install my project I have an error which say that my **app.config** doesn't exist.

[image: file not find]

Comment: I think you could write what you need to the app config and pick them up from there in the service.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208442/change-app-config-during-installation

Comment: @NDJ I see the example but how can I target my app.config file in my ProjectInstaller ?

Comment: @NDJ I see the example but how can I target my app.config file in my ProjectInstaller ?

Comment: isn't that exactly what the example is doing?  Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"].ToString() + "UpdateReportService.exe.config";

Comment: @NDJ the problem is my app.config is not in the installation path

Comment: It will be called "{MainExe}.config" not "app.config" when installed. Replace {MainExe} accordingly. You can get the actual name from the \bin\Debug folder of the service.

Comment: @RyanThomas the installation work fine but I can't run to my service even if I use the debugger. And when I go to {MainExe}.config the dbName is still totodb

Comment: I have added an answer to set the config file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me. You will need to replace ConsoleApp2 with your output filename.

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    string dbName = Context.Parameters["dbname"].ToString();
    string xml = Context.Parameters["name"].ToString() + "ConsoleApp2.exe.config";

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(xml);

    XmlNode dbNameNode = document.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key='dbName']");

    dbNameNode.Attributes["value"].Value = dbName;

    document.Save(xml);
}
```

and my custom action data is:

/name="[TARGETDIR]\" /dbname=[EDITA1]

You can add MessageBox and things in to aid debugging.

Comment: Thank you your the best !
I have my program stop because I have this error : 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'

ConfigurationErrorsException: Only one <configSections> element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root <configuration> element. (C:\t-win\WindowsService1.exe.Config line 6)

Comment: In your app.config you <appSettings> element will need moving below the <configSections> element.